# Table Validation Weirdness

Tags: html, validation, html-table

I'm having a strange validation issue that I can't seem to figure out.

Why would the first td cause a validation error? Is it something to do with the way I am specifying my widths?

http://jsbin.com/esogu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are specifying your widths using deprecated HTML attributes instead of CSS. (The validator is collapsing duplicate error messages).